# Select and Delete have different values

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using the following commands to find and delete duplicates. If the column 1 and column 2 have the exact same values on another row, that is a duplicate row. Since the database is kinda big (millions of rows), it should have some filter on the dates and the company that I'm looking at.

The amount of itens with count higher than 2 are really low, but the amount of rows are really far apart between these two commands.

Note: I'm a beginner in SQL and the name of the column is not date.

```
SELECT column1, column2, date, COUNT( * ) 
FROM table1 
WHERE company_id = 10 and date BETWEEN "2017-11-01" AND "2017-11-30"
GROUP BY column1, column2, date
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1;
```

```
DELETE t1 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id AND 
    t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND
    t1.column2 = t2.column2 AND
    t1.company_id = 10 AND
    t1.date between "2017-11-01" and "2017-11-30";
```

What is wrong with my logic?
Thank you for reading or helping.

Comment: You also need to test `t2.date` in the DELETE query. `AND t2.date BETWEEN ...`

Comment: also t2.company_id.  better done in an ON clause `JOIN table1 t2 on t2.id > t1.id and t2.column1=t1.column1 and t2.column2=t1.column2 and t2.company_id=10 and t2.date between "2017-11-01" and "2017-11-30"`

Comment: please avoid "kinda big" and the like; big means different things to different people, so we don't know if you mean a few hundred rows or a few billion.

Comment: Thank you @ysth. I'll keep that in mind the next time that I ask something here.
Again, thank you for helping out.

Comment: `t1.column1 = t2.column2` should be `t1.column1 = t2.column1`

Comment: It's a mistype thank you for point that out.